# HTC HD2 Compass API

Tags: compact-framework

Does HTC have a Compass API for devices like the HD2?

I'm hoping to be able to work with it from .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy enough to get the info you need to write a C# wrapper from [this XDA Developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=592374).